# Passing function with the innerHTML in ng-class

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate, angularjs-ng-class

I'm trying to create an ng-class clause in AngularJS that evaluates the length of the contents and assigns a class accordingly, the problem is that the text is retrieved using the angular-translate service, so when trying to pass the variable in the ng-class, it is still undefined.

Here's what I've tried so far

```
<div ng-class="{'title-long-text': $controller.isTextTooLong(common.title),
                'title': !$controller.isTextTooLong(common.title)}"
     translate>common.title</div>
```

the JS

```
this.isTextTooLong = function(text) {
    if (typeof text === 'undefined' || !text) {
        return;
    }
    debugger;
    console.log(text);
    return true;
};
```

PS : this function is currently for testing purposes only, it is still a work in progress

Comment: can you create a working code snippet of you issue. Use plunker/jsfiddle/codepen etc for that.

Comment: I'll try to create one in an hour or so if no body was able to answer it till then, It would just take some time to re-create the structure

Comment: What about using an `ng-if`?

Comment: If `common.title` is an AngularJS Expression, it should be enclosed in double curly brackets `{{ }}`, when used as contents of a `<div>` element. If you wish to watch the the innerHTML of a `<div>`, you need to write a [custom directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).